# Подключение к компьютеру из вне

Tags: windows, безопасность, port

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите пожалуйста, могут ли из вне (из интернета) подключится ко мне? Если ещё и IP знают.
Открытые порты на скрине.

Если да, то какие порты закрыть?

Comment: Закрыть все, конечно же

Comment: http://2ip.ru эти порты видит открытыми?

Comment: @andreymal, не согласен. Судя по скрину - человек смотрит виндовой проге на локалхосте. И если ща рубануть 445 и 139 - может выйти весело.